# Only show associated data in v-for

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, v-for

I have the following code:

```
<template>
<div>
    <div v-for="title in titles">
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
        <a @click="showSub">Click Here</a>
        <div v-if="subshown">
            Shown
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                subshown: false,
                titles: []
            }
        },
        methods: {
            showSub: function () {
                this.subshown = true;
                // do something more
            }
        }        
    }
</script>
```

When i now click on the `Click Here` Button, the associated `subshown` from the current title should be shown. At the moment, when i click on `Click Here`, all `subshown` are shown.

How to implement that only the associated is shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a property called `currentIndex` then update it using the click event and use it in conditional rendering :

```
<template>
<div>
    <div v-for="(title,index) in titles">
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
        <a @click="showSub(index)">Click Here</a>
        <div v-if="currentIndex===index">
            Shown
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                currentIndex:-1,
                titles: []
            }
        },
        methods: {
            showSub: function (index) {
              this.currentIndex=this.currentIndex===index?-1:index
                // do something more
            }
        }        
    }
</script>
```