# Toggle button text on a loop VUE

Tags: vue.js

I have a loop with products, each with a product card.
I want to be able to toggle the button when clicked from `Add to cart` to `Remove from cart`.

**The problem is all of the products buttons toggle at the same time, and I wan't ONLY the individual product card buttons to be toggled referencing each individual product.**

**In my HTML**

```
      <div v-for="product of products" :key="product.id">
         <span class="btn btn-primary mt-5 modal-toggle-btn"  @click="addGift(product, text, 'index')" v-show="!isAdded">Añadir a la box</span>
         <span class="btn btn-primary mt-5 modal-toggle-btn" @click="removeGift(product, 'index')" v-show="isAdded">Quitar de la box</span>
      </div>
```

**Vue data**

```
isAdded: false
```

**My Vue methods**

```
  addGift(product, index){
     this.campaign.selectedproducts.push({name: product.name });
     this.isAdded = true
  },
  removeGift(product, index){
     this. campaign.selectedproducts.splice(index, 1)
     this.isAdded = false
  },
```

Comment: You're looking to something like in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64895051/8172857)

Comment: Hi there , I tried to put an index into the params but I don't know how to use the method in the correct way (updated answer). Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by text? is it a data property?

Comment: Sorry it was only for testing purposes, fixed question

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to:

1. Divide the product buttons as an individual component.
2. Use `addedIds` as an array to store added product ids instead of `isAdded` boolean.
3. Communicate parent and child click events with [Vue event handling](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html).
4. Store clicked product `id` in to the `addedProductId` on click events.
5. Check against `addedProductId` to make sure a product was added or
   not in child component.

**Example:**

**ProductButtons.vue (child component)**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <span class="btn btn-primary mt-5 modal-toggle-btn"  @click="addGift" v-show="!isAdded">Añadir a la box</span>
    <span class="btn btn-primary mt-5 modal-toggle-btn" @click="removeGift" v-show="isAdded">Quitar de la box</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ProductButtons",
  props: {
    product: { type: Object, required: true },
    addedIds: { type: Array, required: true },
  },
  computed: {
    isAdded() {
      return this.addedIds.indexOf(this.product.id) > -1;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    addGift(){
      this.$emit('addGift', this.product);
    },
    removeGift(product){
      this.$emit('addGift', this.product);
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

**In Your HTML**

```
<template v-for="product of products" :key="product.id">
    <product-buttons :product="product" :addedIds="addedIds" @addGift="addGift" @removeGift="removeGift"></product-buttons>
</template>
```

**Vue data**

```
addedIds: []
```

**Your Vue methods**

```
  addGift(product){
     this.campaign.selectedproducts.push({name: product.name });
     // save product id as an added id
     const index = this.addedIds.indexOf(product.id);
     if (index === -1) {
         this.addedIds.push(product.id);
     }
  },
  removeGift(product){
     this.campaign.selectedproducts.splice(index, 1);
     // remove product id
     const index = this.addedIds.indexOf(product.id);
     if (index > -1) {
         this.addedIds.splice(index, 1);
     }
  },
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Zugor, I'm trying to implement this in my Rails app

Comment: You are welcome. May be you can accept the answer if it's a correct answer for you.