# Vue v-for is displaying more than one image on click

Tags: vue.js

I am using vue to show a photo that is being pulled from a mysql DB.
I loop through the images but when I click to show, all the images show instead of just the one that I want to show (the single image button I clicked). How do I get only one image to show up at a time?

UPDATED

```
 <div>
   <div v-for="(image, index) in images" :key="index">
      <div class="dropdown">
         <div>
            <a class="dropdown-item preview-link" @click="togglePreview(index)">
            Preview
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div v-if="currentIndex === index" class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-md" role="image" style="max-width: 700px;">
         <div class="modal-content" style="overflow: hidden;">
            <div class="modal-header">
               <h5 class="modal-title">{{image.title}}</h5>
               <button type="button" class="close modal-close-button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
               <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
               </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
               <img :src="'/storage/images/' + image.name + '.jpg'">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

In my vue methods:

```
 togglePreview(index) {
  this.currentIndex = this.currentIndex === index?-1:index
},
```

Vue Data

```
data() {
    return {
       currentIndex: -1,
    }
  },
```

Comment: you're looking to something like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64895051/8172857 ?

Comment: There might be an issue while using `index` instead of `image` itself here. If you open an image with index 2 and after that you add another image at index 2 then this new image will be open instead of an old one.

Comment: @Anatoly so should I use the image object instead?

Comment: @PA_GW I recommend you to pass `image` instead of `index` to `togglePreview` and store something like `openedImage` in `data` section.

Comment: @Anatoly, I just give him an idea to provide something unique, he could use image url, name or id instead of index

Comment: @Anatoly what would be stored in ```openedImage``` ?

Comment: clicked `image` object itself. Default value should be `null`

Comment: If you have an unique prop in `image` object it would be even better to use it in case you will wish to refresh a list of images and restore the previously opened image state.

Comment: @Anatoly in reality there's no issue, because the index is updated every time he clicks on  an image to preview the index should be updated based on the clicked image.

Comment: I updated the code to show what I have now, this seems to be working but when an image shows it doesnt open in a modal it just shows in place on the screen so I cant scroll up or down or see the whole image

Comment: This could be related to your style not to the logic